# Voice audio indexing and search for Linux or Android

Tags: android, linux, search, speech-recognition, voice

I use a voice recorder as a memory prosthetic. I imagine there are a number of professions that would use a voice audio database, like maybe journalism, or anyone recording and reviewing interviews and meetings.

I need something I can install and run offline on Linux, or Android. Necessary features: Manages the audio files from various sources, including import and transcription (voice-to-text), and has a friendly interface for search, playback, and seeking. Privacy-respecting: uploading all my audio is not an option.